# $\exp(-i \infty)$ is "Not a Number" according to MATLAB. Why?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, matlab, floating-point

I ran into this problem while trying to understand the Laplace transform via MATLAB.

exp(-i*Inf)

> NaN + NaNi

But,

exp(-Inf)

> 0

Furthermore,

> syms t
>   fun= exp(-(0+i)*t)
>   answer=int(fun,0,Inf)

returns

> NaN

But it is able to solve it if no limits are given.

> answer =
>    exp(-t*1i)*1i

Something about Infinity is not quite right with MATLAB. Any suggestions on how to make it right?

Comment: Not a question about math as far as I can tell.

Comment: @YiFan Debatable. It's a question about floating-point arithmetic, and I think it's ok. It's not about Matlab syntax, and actually it's not about Matlab.

Comment: I'd imagine that Matlab would tell you that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ equals $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n$ doesn't converge. Computer algebra systems often don't check variables against the region of convergence - there are lots of quirks (and some bugs) of these tools that one has to learn, so don't just treat its output as fact.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Matlab is not a computer algebra system: no symbolic computations (unless you have the Mupad toolbox). The question here is about floating point. But I agree, no output from any mathematical software should be regarded blindly as mathematical fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple. The limit of $$e^{-i\phi}$$ as $\phi\to\infty$ simply doesn't exist.

You see this since we have $$e^{-i\phi}=\cos\phi-i\sin\phi.$$ Letting $\phi$ become infinite, we cannot assign any definite value to the trigonometric functions on RHS.

On the other hand, we have that $e^{-x}$ is vanishing when $x\to\infty$ since $e^{-x}=1/e^x.$

Comment: if e^(-iϕ) is not well defined then how do we calculate the Laplace Transform Integral for say..the unit step function?

Comment: @underdog No one said anything about the complex exponential not being well-defined. It is. What I said is that this quantity has no limit as you make the argument go to infinity. If you want to ask a separate question about Laplace transformation, do that in a separate post properly, instead of halfheartedly like you're doing here. :)

Comment: @underdog If you search "unit step function Laplace transform" on Google there are some good hits. Khan academy did a lesson: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform/properties-of-laplace-transform/v/laplace-transform-of-the-unit-step-function

Comment: As for why $e^{-i \infty}$ is undefined, think about how $e^{i\theta}$ rotates around the circle at constant speed. It just keeps going. Therefore it cannot converge to anything.

Comment: @underdog Well, $0^i$ is not $0.$ We usually define $a^{i\phi}$ to be $e^{i\phi\log a}$ for values of $a$ different from $e.$ Then it follows that $0^i=e^{i\log 0}=\cos\log 0+i\sin \log 0,$ which gets you back to square one.

Comment: @Allawonder yes, I just realized my stupidity...Sorry about that.